# Is it possible to index out NA's from a column?

Tags: r, indexing, subset, data-analysis, na

Iam working R in RStudio and doing some analysis about crimes in chicago. I have a date column in my dataset which I separated into 3 columns (year, month, day). Now I would like to see how many crimes per year happened in which month. My code and filtering is working perfect I just have somewhere in the dataset (in the year, month, day) columns NA's. I tried everything to get them out, but didnt work. Does somebody has any idea how I can get them out, or is it possible to get them out with indexing? For example something like this `Year[-NA]`.

This is how my code looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
library(xts)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

homicide <- cc[cc$Primary.Type == "HOMICIDE",]
homicideAnalysis <- homicide %>% group_by(Year, Month) %>% summarise(Total = n())

ggplot(homicideAnalysis, aes(Year, Month, fill = Total)) +
  geom_tile(size = 1, color = "white") +
  scale_fill_viridis()  +
  geom_text(aes(label = Total), color='white') +
  ggtitle("Homicides in Chicago")
```

And here is a screenshot of the plot, where you can see the NA at month and at year:

[Homicides in Chicago Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMROy.png)

PS: `unique(cc$Year)` gives me this output

```
 [1] 04   03   01   02   <NA> 06   05   07   08   09   11   10   16   15   12   14  
[17] 13   17  
Levels: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(homicideAnalysis %>% na.omit(), aes(Year, Month, fill = Total)) +
  geom_tile(size = 1, color = "white") +
  scale_fill_viridis()  +
  geom_text(aes(label = Total), color='white') +
  ggtitle("Homicides in Chicago")
```

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it helped.